# Traveling to Sri Lanka with Refugee Travel Document

Tags: transit, refugees, sri-lanka

I am a refugee and granted a refugee passport by Italy. I am planning to go to Sri Lanka for tourism and obtained ETA from Sri Lanka. I am originally from Pakistan but do not have passport or ID from my country. For travel I have just this Refugee Travel Document and Resident Permit of Italy along with the ETA approval email from Sri Lanka.

Can I go to Sri Lanka via Abu Dhabi or Zurich without any problem with airline/immigration as there is no direct flight from Italy to Sri Lanka.

Please help me regarding this question, your answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you travel to Srilanka with an ETA and Refugee travel document ?

Answer (score 2):

In principle you can be a tourist anywhere in the Schengen area for 90 days out of every 180 days using your permesso di soggiorno. Going to Zurich is not a problem.

You will also need to carry your documento di viaggio. This is your passport-replacing travel document.

You do not need a visa to transit in the UAE as long as you remain airside. If you want to enter Abu Dhabi you should arrange a visa in advance through Etihad (you can [do this on their web site](https://uaevisas.etihad.com/echannels/web/client/etihad/index.html#/dashboard?lang=en) after you have booked your flight).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Hampton. You gave a very detailed and informative answer, i greatly appreciate it.